# fgrep for exact matches but -f file has substrings of other elements

Tags: macos, unix, grep

I have a weird fgrep problem that seems specific for Mac OS X (the unexpected behavior does not happen on Ubuntu Linux).

My file ("qlist") has these lines in it (with no spaces)

```
CMGC_CDK1
CMGC_CDK2
CMGC_CDK10
```

My file "biglist" has these lines in it:

```
CMGC_CDK1
CMGC_CDK10
CMGC_CDK11A
CMGC_CDK11B
CMGC_CDK12
CMGC_CDK13
CMGC_CDK14
CMGC_CDK15
CMGC_CDK16
CMGC_CDK17
CMGC_CDK18
CMGC_CDK19
CMGC_CDK2
CMGC_CDK20
```

I want to issue an fgrep command that gives me back only the exact matches (by line) of what's in qlist. I should get this:

```
fgrep -someflags -f qlist biglist

CMGC_CDK1
CMGC_CDK2
CMGC_CDK10
```

but the flags -x and -w don't give the expected result.

If I issue the command:

```
 fgrep -w -f qlist biglist
```

or

```
 fgrep -x -f qlist biglist
```

I get

```
CMGC_CDK1
CMGC_CDK2
```

What I expected (and wanted was):

```
CMGC_CDK1
CMGC_CDK10
CMGC_CDK2
```

It's as if the fact that the search item file ("qlist" in the command) has one line that is a substring of another (CMGC_CDK1, CMGC_CDK10) somehow suppresses using CMGC_CDK10 as a search item.

Note: on Ubuntu linux, I get the expected result. This seems specific for Mac OS X fgrep. I am doing this on Mac OS X, 10.15.1, in a Unix terminal window with the default installed fgrep.

What am I missing? How do I make this work?

Thanks,
Roland

Comment: I tested on my Mac and I am getting 3 lines in output. Make sure you don't have a trailing whitespace or `\r` in both files.

Comment: Thanks. I get no detected strings from these commands.   egrep '\r' qlist biglist     or     grep ' ' qlist biglist     Maybe i need to update my Mac OS or at least grep.

Comment: Mac "cat" does not have that option. but -e and -v and -t display non-printing characters in various ways, and none of them shows any problem. The example files were manually created with emacs text editor (as an example) so shouldn't have invisible nonprinting characters.

Comment: Roland see my suggested solution in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU grep in macOS terminal it works as expected.

```
grep -w -f qlist biglist
```

My computer has GNU grep installed. You can easily install it by:

```
brew install grep
```

It will make your life easier as Mac user. You can also install coreutilities which allows you to use GNU versions of the commands on Mac terminal. You can still use macOS versions. This will also solve your `cat` command issue.

```
brew install coreutils
```

When I try to use `fgrep` this is the warning I get on macOS Terminal:

```
fgrep: warning: fgrep is obsolescent; using ggrep -F
CMGC_CDK1
CMGC_CDK10
CMGC_CDK2
```

Please note that ggrep simply refers to GNU grep in my system

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks!  Appears to be a bug (or highly undesirable feature) of Mac's unix grep.

Comment: If this solved your problem, I would appreciate an up vote.

Comment: I've never posted on stack overflow before but have used it very often to read about how to solve problems. So when I tried to "upvote" it said I need a "reputation score" of at least 15. I think it recorded it but it won't show it on this page. But I have "accepted" the answer as correct and bookmarked it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you Roland. Just little motivation for me to visit the site more often. It worked.